# Is there a tale of Zeus having sex with a deer?

Tags: greek, myth-identification, zeus

I heard about a myth saying Zeus had sex with a deer, but after hours of research, I hold nothing. Can anyone tell me of this myth?

I am especially interested in acquiring any information about a supposed child that came of this union.

Comment: The first place to search for anything like that is Ovid.

Comment: I tried a Perseus search (English) for "deer/hart/hind/roe" in Ovid's *Metamorphoses* and Apollodorus, both, and found no such tale.

Comment: Not as far as I know *(but he probably did get around to it as some point;)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the story of the nymph [Taygete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taygete), one of the Pleiades. When Zeus pursued her, Artemis transformed her to a hind (or a cow) with golden horns. However, Zeus wasn't fooled by the disguise and raped the nymph. The result of their union is [Lacedaemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacedaemon_(mythology)), the legendary founder of Sparta.